# How to add line-breaks into "Multiple lines of text" field when using ToString()

Tags: string, multiple-lines-of-text

I have a list field of the type "Multiple Lines of Text". When I retrieve it in my code-behind using `item["field"].ToString()`, it prints out the text, but without line-breaks. How can I add line breaks to the text?

What I have:

```
<p>Text text text.
Text text text.
Text Text Text.</p>
```

What I want:

```
<p>Text text text.<br/>
Text text text.<br/>
Text Text Text.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the below way:

1) While creating a multi-line list column, create as a enhanced rich text as below:
[image]

2) While retrieving text using the below c# code

Using Span:

```
SPFieldMultiLineText mlt = list.Fields.GetField("MultiLineField") as SPFieldMultiLineText;
spanID.InnerHtml = mlt.GetFieldValueAsHtml(list["MultiLineField"] as string);
```

Using SharePoint TextBox:

Control

```
<SharePoint:InputFormTextBox ID="txtID" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" RichTextMode="FullHtml" RichText="true" />
```

c# code:

```
txtID.Text = mlt.GetFieldValueAsHtml(list["MultiLineField"] as string);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found to retrieve HTML-formated text with line-brakes is replacement. SharePoint classes and methods didn't help.

```
Convert.ToString(item["field"]).Replace("\r\n", "<br>");
```